Emscripten Multiply defined symbol, vtable
I have compiled a variety of LLVM Object files.
However, when linking them together, I get this error:
error: Linking globals named '_ZTV4CRpg': symbol multiply defined!

I debugged and found there was a conflict between two objects: rpg.o and weapons.o. They both had the _ZTV4CRpg symbol in them. This translates to a vtable for CRpg. And that would make sense, as they both define CRpg. However, the definitions of CRpg are totally different. Why would this happen and is there a fix?
Here are the two C++ source files: weapons.cpp, rpg.cpp
I found a bug in LLVM regarding this issue but I cannot apply the latest version as the program I am trying to compile is 7 years old, the patch is 1 year old, and I need to avoid compatibility issues as much as possible.
Using modern compilers, however, it is shown that the symbols are NOT the same:
$ nm build/dlls/CMakeFiles/server.dir/rpg.cpp.o | grep _ZTV4CRpg 
                  U _ZTV4CRpg 
$ nm build/dlls/CMakeFiles/server.dir/weapons.cpp.o | grep _ZTV4CRpg
 0000000000000000 V _ZTV4CRpg

However on the LLVM build they are both 0000000000000000 V _ZTV4CRpg
Note I used nm and grep to scan for conflicting symbols.

This is simply illegal C++. At least one of the classes should be in unnamed namespace { ... } to not collide.

"...However, the definitions of CRpg are totally different..." Breaks the one-definition-rule, no diagnostic required. Definitions and ODR (One Definition Rule) "... There can be more than one definition in a program of each of the following: class type ... as long as all of the following is true: ... each definition consists of the same sequence of tokens ..."_

you should make a [mcve]/sscce

@HolyBlackCat Is it really if dozens of other people managed to compile it? It's the Half-Life SDK, I'm sure it would have been compiled multiple times.

@HolyBlackCat For proof, I just compiled it with regular GCC ‍♂️. Worked fine.

@MissingUser Undefined Behaviour includes appearing to work; usually until a live customer demo.

@RichardCritten
nm build/dlls/CMakeFiles/server.dir/rpg.cpp.o | grep _ZTV4CRpg
U _ZTV4CRpg
nm build/dlls/CMakeFiles/server.dir/weapons.cpp.o | grep _ZTV4CRpg
0000000000000000 V _ZTV4CRpg
However on the LLVM build they are both 0000000000000000 V _ZTV4CRpg
Help please?

As HolyBlackCat said, one (or every) library should be in it's own unique namespace.  Collisions like this are the main reason namespaces were introduced to the language.  2 classes with the same name and different definition(s) break the One Definition Rule and No Diagnostic is Required.
